# How can I get Browser name from WCF Service without enabling ASP.NET Compatibility mode?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I tried using HttpContext.Current.Request and also OperationContext and WebOperationContext but not getting desired results . Is there any way we can get the browser Name and version from WCF Service?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = Request.Browser;
var name = browser.Browser;

or

Request.Browser.Browser;
Request.Browser.Version;

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by using [Request.Browser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.browser(v=vs.110).aspx)

Request.Browser gives browser version information along with some extra information regarding the browser capabilities.

So you can check simply by doing like this or go for some other check

```
if (Request.Browser.Type.Contains("Firefox"))
{
} 
...
```

[User Agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.useragent.aspx) also gives browser information, But it gives you a raw string about the browser.

Comment: I am not getting Request.Browser even after using System.Web namespace in my WCF Service . Is there any other way possible ?

Comment: Have you added reference for System.Web dll?